# Cannot establish connection to localhost websocket server (Next, Prisma, TRPC Subscription)

Tags: next.js, websocket, trpc

I have a Next web app running smoothly with `prisma` and `trpc` (t3-stack). I want to create a `ws` server for my trpc subscriptions (I'm trying to create notification alerts within the app). I see some solutions written in PHP or JavaScript but I do not know how to apply them to t3-stack. I do not intend at this moment to use `wss` and I just want to explore `ws` as a beginner.

Based on TRPC documentations, I did the following:

ws.ts

```
import ws from "ws";
import { appRouter } from "./api/root";
import { applyWSSHandler } from "@trpc/server/adapters/ws"
import { createContext } from "./context";

const wss = new ws.Server({
    port: 3001,
});

const handler = applyWSSHandler({ wss, router: appRouter, createContext });
wss.on('connection', (ws) => {
    console.log(`➕➕ Connection (${wss.clients.size})`);
    ws.once('close', () => {
        console.log(`➖➖ Connection (${wss.clients.size})`);
    });
});

console.log('✅ WebSocket Server listening on ws://localhost:3001');

process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
    console.log('SIGTERM');
    handler.broadcastReconnectNotification();
    wss.close();
});
```

api.ts

```
import { createTRPCProxyClient, createWSClient, httpBatchLink, loggerLink, splitLink, wsLink } from "@trpc/client";
import { createTRPCNext } from "@trpc/next";
import { type inferRouterInputs, type inferRouterOutputs } from "@trpc/server";
import superjson from "superjson";
import { type AppRouter } from "../server/api/root";

const getBaseUrl = () => {
  if (typeof window !== "undefined") return ""; // browser should use relative url
  if (process.env.VERCEL_URL) return `https://${process.env.VERCEL_URL}`; // SSR should use vercel url
  return `http://localhost:${process.env.PORT ?? 3000}`; // dev SSR should use localhost
};

const url = `${getBaseUrl()}/api/trpc`

const wsClient = createWSClient({
  url: 'ws://localhost:3001',
})

export const api = createTRPCNext<AppRouter>({
  config({ ctx }) {
    return {
      transformer: superjson,
      links: [
        splitLink({
          condition: (op) => op.type === "subscription",
          true: wsLink({
            client: wsClient
          }),
          false: httpBatchLink({
            url
          }),
        }),
        httpBatchLink({
          url
        }),
        loggerLink({
          enabled: (opts) =>
            process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ||
            (opts.direction === "down" && opts.result instanceof Error),
        }),

      ],
      headers() {
        if (ctx?.req) {
          return { ...ctx.req.headers }
        }
        return {}
      }
    };
  },
  ssr: false,
});

export type RouterInputs = inferRouterInputs<AppRouter>;
export type RouterOutputs = inferRouterOutputs<AppRouter>;
```

To test the setup above, I did a simple subscription API at the backend and use it in frontend.

router code

```
onNewNotification: protectedProcedure.subscription(() => {
    return observable<Notifications>((emit) => {
      const onAdd = (data: Notifications) => {
        emit.next(data)
      }

      ee.on('add', onAdd)

      return () => {
        ee.off('add', onAdd)
      }
    })
  }),
```

front-end

```
  api.notifications.onNewNotification.useSubscription(undefined, {
    onData(newNotif) {
      addNotification([newNotif])
      console.log("New notifications loaded!")
    },
    onError(err) {
      console.error('Subscription error', err)
    }
  })
```

The app is running

```
> next dev

  ▲ Next.js 13.5.4
  - Local:        http://localhost:3000
  - Environments: .env

 ✓ Ready in 4.1s
```

However, the console reports that the wsClient cannot connect to the ws server.

```
wsLink.mjs:82 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3001/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I need some guidance and explanation as I find other similar posts confusing. This is my first NodeJS project.